# Java NIO blocking/non-blocking issue when downloading from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, nio, google-cloud-storage

I tried downloading from Google Cloud Storage

```
Storage.Objects.Get get = storage.objects().get(BUCKET_NAME, fileName);
Log.i("Downloader", "Media File verified");
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream =  new BufferedInputStream(get.executeMediaAsInputStream());
Log.i("Downloader", "InputStreamCreated");
ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(bufferedInputStream);
Log.i("Downloader", "Channel Created");
return ((SelectableChannel) readableByteChannel).configureBlocking(false);
```

When I try to register this with a selector, nothing happens.
It simply hangs.

Help please

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you leave out the BufferedInputStream  ? i.e. rather do  Channels.newChannel(get.executeMediaAsInputStream());

Comment: yes, same issue. I thought bufferedInputStream would help, but it didnt.

Comment: I have rerouted the data using a Pipe as a temp solution. Reading directly from the input-stream works, as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have failed at the `configureBlocking()` call. You can't put channels acquired from `Channels.newChannel()` into non-blocking mode. See the Javadoc. *Ergo* you can't register them with a Selector either.

In fact I would have thought it should fail at the typecast to `SelectableChannel`.

Are you sure you haven't missed an exception?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct. It should fail at typecast to Selectable-channel. I went through the java doc, I think I messed up exception handling at some level. Anyway, a good way to achieve non-blocking IO in this situation is to use a pipe.
final Pipe.SinkChannel sinkChannel = pipe.sink();
final Pipe.SourceChannel sourceChannel = pipe.source();
final byte [] bytes = new byte[StaticData.BUF_SIZE];

Simple write into the sink in a blocking fashion, and read from source in non-blocking way :)